# What is the "Mission Expense" line-item in your energy-credit budget?

Tags: stellaris

So, most things in Stellaris are hover-over-able, and give a useful break-down for whatever you're curious about; but I have a 20.00cr/mo line-item for ‘Mission Expense’, and hovering over it gives me no details. Does anybody know what this is referring to?

Comment: Do you have any missions underway in your Situation Log?

Comment: Infiltration or Uplift Missions?

Comment: found something regarding this 'Mission Expense'. Check it out, seems like an incomplete feature: https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/observation-posts-in-sectors.927680/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That expense includes the cost of Infiltration and Enlighten missions on observation posts.

There may be other costs included at times as well, but every time I've tried to balance the books I've been able to account for the expense with just my observation posts.

Answer (score 0):

That is the expense of running an infiltrate mission via the observation post.

Comment: So you're saying there's no expense?